# Angularjs MVC skeleton project with user management

Tags: angularjs, model-view-controller, twitter-bootstrap-3

I'm looking for a kickstart angularjs project with a basic MVC skeleton which shows as well user management, sing up and sing in UI and may using css bootstrap ... any good out there?

[Here](https://github.com/angular/angular.js/wiki/Projects-using-AngularJS) I found nice ones, may help others ..

Comment: Have a look at [`yeoman`](http://yeoman.io) in general, [`yeoman angular`](https://github.com/yeoman/generator-angular) in particular  and [other generators](http://yeoman.io/community-generators.html).

Answer (score 1):

May be it is too late to answer you but I have found [aspnetboilerplate.com](http://aspnetboilerplate.com/) a nice N-Layered tier project to start with.

*They claim:*

> ASP.NET Boilerplate is a starting point for new modern web applications using best practices and most popular tools. It's aimed to be a solid model, a general-purpose application framework and a project template.

1. You can select which frameworks you need to use in you project.
2. Name your project.
3. Then download it.